# I want to be able to search for a Post in the Post table based on whats inside a different table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Inside my post table is my designerID which is the same in the Designer table, when i make a post the designerID is set to the same as it is in the designer table, I want to have a search at the top to allow users to find designers based on what they do, i.e logo design, web design.

[The designer table where I have recorded in Boolean what the designer does](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fEMp.png)

Is it possible for me to filter posts based on what ive got?

thanks in advance

Comment: you will need to use category system .. when you add a post you can choose a category for the post .. based on that you can make a search function to filter posts with certain categories

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! how do I go about adding a category system? is this to be done when the post is being made? one thing im considering is: get logo from designer where id = id, then if logo = 1 or 0 echo Logo, then using a javascript search bar

Comment: **Another solution**
if you want something simple just go for the tags. when you create a post you should have input field called tags,, you put in it the tags you want like logo design etc .. and you make a query on a search field like this: $query = "SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE post_tags = '{$search}'

this is the easiest way

Comment: Could you explain your question a little more? Are you trying to get the ID of a designer that does 'logo' by example?

Comment: So I have a page that's currently outputting every post but what I want is for a user to be able to filter these posts based on what they're looking for, I made the designer choose what they do with check boxes in the registration form but when they post they just add content and a link, I want the user to be able to click a button that says logo which will then only show the posts from designers who ticked logo

Comment: @CiaranBeatty Alright, does the number in your table represent the amount of posts or does it mean whether they do the type of work or not? 1 being yes and 0 being no.

Comment: Oh, in Boolean, my bad.

Comment: Yeah so the number means yes or no I have only allowed the designer to make one post

Comment: Check my answer below and tell whether that works for you or not.

Comment: Yes I think that's exactly what I'll need I can assign that to a variable then when I'm on the post page with every post displayed can I search for posts by designers who make logos by doing get * from post where designerID = $logodesign

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want the user to be able to click a button that says logo which will then only show the posts from designers who ticked logo.

As you said, you are saving the type of work they do in a boolean.

- 1 representing that they do the type of work
- 0 representing that they do not do the type of work

If you would like to select all the designers that do logos, this would be your query.

`SELECT * FROM designers WHERE logo = 1`

This query will give you all the designers that do logos.

You do not need an additional table for categories.

Answer (score 0):

#### option 1

If you determine that your type will not increase , you can just change
`bool` to `int` , when  user create a new post, increment the number.
So you can use numbers to determine if he is working on some type,and easy to find
out who is really good at some type.

#### option 2

create `category` to recode post types ,  `category_counter` to record the numbers of designer working types

`category`

```
id  | name
--- | ---
1   | logo
2   | website
```

`post_counter`

```
id  | designer_id | category_id | number
--- | ---         | ---         | ---
1   | 1           | 1           | 10  
2   | 1           | 2           | 20  
3   | 2           | 1           | 5
```

Maybe my answer is wrong. I apologize for failing to understand the question .